# Washed out color in ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

I don't understand why my material produces a faded image, any clues would be appreciated. Here is the image, terrain uses the shader in question.
[image]
As you can see the material looks really faded comapred to other objects in the scene.

Here's the same scene with `#include <encoding_fragment>` removed:
[image]

Rendering is done directly to the screen and not to a render-target. Here are relevant renderer settings:

```
webGLRenderer.gammaInput = true;
webGLRenderer.gammaOutput = true;
webGLRenderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;
webGLRenderer.physicallyBasedShading = true;
```

here's the fragment shader of the material:

```
void main() { 
    vec4 splatData = normalize( texture2D(splatMap, vUv) );
    vec2 uvT = vUv*diffuseMapRepeat;
    vec4 diffuseData0 = texture2D(diffuseMap0, uvT);
    vec4 diffuseData1 = texture2D(diffuseMap1, uvT);
    vec4 diffuseData2 = texture2D(diffuseMap2, uvT);
    vec4 diffuseData3 = texture2D(diffuseMap3, uvT);
    vec4 splatDiffuseColor = blendSplatTextures(diffuseData0, diffuseData1, diffuseData2, diffuseData3, splatData);

    splatDiffuseColor.a = 1.0;

    #ifdef DIFFUSE_GRAIN
        randomBlend(vUv, splatDiffuseColor.rgb, 0.03);
    #endif


    vec2 gridOverlayCoord = computeGridPosition(vUv);
    vec2 gridOverlayUV = gridOverlayCoord/(gridResolution);
    vec4 gridOverlayColor = texture2D(diffuseGridOverlayMap, gridOverlayUV);
    vec2 gridOverlayEdge = 1.0-step(0.5-gridBorderWidth*0.5, abs( fract(gridOverlayUV*gridResolution) - 0.5 ));
    float gridOverlayAlpha = min(gridOverlayEdge.x,gridOverlayEdge.y);
    gridOverlayColor *= gridOverlayAlpha;

    #include <clipping_planes_fragment>

    splatDiffuseColor = mapTexelToLinear( splatDiffuseColor );

    vec4 diffuseColor = blendAlpha( vec4(splatDiffuseColor.rgb,opacity) , gridOverlayColor);
    diffuseColor.a *=  opacity;

    ReflectedLight reflectedLight = ReflectedLight( vec3( 0.0 ), vec3( 0.0 ), vec3( 0.0 ), vec3( 0.0 ) );
    vec3 totalEmissiveRadiance = emissive;

    #include <logdepthbuf_fragment>

    #include <alphamap_fragment>
    #include <alphatest_fragment>

    // make surface completely diffuse
    float specularStrength = 0.0;
    #include <emissivemap_fragment>
    // accumulation
    reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse = getAmbientLightIrradiance( ambientLightColor );
    #ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED
        reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse += ( gl_FrontFacing ) ? vIndirectFront : vIndirectBack;
    #else
        reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse += vIndirectFront;
    #endif

    #include <lightmap_fragment> 


    reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse *= BRDF_Diffuse_Lambert( diffuseColor.rgb );

    #ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED

        reflectedLight.directDiffuse = ( gl_FrontFacing ) ? vLightFront : vLightBack;

    #else

        reflectedLight.directDiffuse = vLightFront;

    #endif

    ${ShaderChunks.clouds_fragment}

    reflectedLight.directDiffuse *= BRDF_Diffuse_Lambert( diffuseColor.rgb ) * getShadowMask();

    // modulation
    #include <aomap_fragment>

    vec3 outgoingLight = reflectedLight.directDiffuse + reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse + totalEmissiveRadiance;

    #include <envmap_fragment>

    gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, diffuseColor.a );

    #include <tonemapping_fragment>
    #include <encodings_fragment>
    #include <fog_fragment>
    #include <dithering_fragment>
}
```

The fragment is modeled after lambert material:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/c94018cb475e1c357671138e78741b1a162e0bf9/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshlambert_frag.glsl.js

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Culprit #1:

using `mapTexelToLinear`, this is loaded based on `Material.map` property, since mine is a custom material and I don't use `map`, it's not set correctly. This needed to be replaced with `sRGBToLinear`.

Useful references:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js#L511
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ae49868c1b0ad53e3680074c961a9f7318d94f13/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/encodings_pars_fragment.glsl.js
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js#L12

Comment: RIght. The code injection only works for built-in materials, so the `mapTexelToLinear()` function will not be properly-defined for your custom `ShaderMaterial`. three.js r.102.